# spring @Aspect can not work with swagger2

Tags: java, swagger, spring-aop, aspect

pom.xml version info:

- springfox-swagger2: 2.5.0
- swagger-core: 1.5.10
- springfox-swagger-ui: 2.6.1
- springboot: 1.5.3

I has a project with swagger2 and springboot.

The project code without @Aspect works very well.The code reads as follows.

```
public interface TestApi {
    WfExecution test(Long temp);
}


@Api(value = "TestAPI")
@RequestMapping(value = "/test")
@RestController
public class TestApiImpl implements TestApi {

    @Override
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test")
    @ApiOperation(value = "", notes = "", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public WfExecution test(@ApiParam(value = "", required = true) @RequestParam(required = true, value = "temp")
                                        Long temp) {
        return new WfExecution();
    }
}
```

the right result:

[image: success picture]

But when I add the follow code, the swagger-ui doesn't show the test-api-impl.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LoggerAop {
    @Before("execution(* com.XXX.controller.impl.TestApiImpl.*(..))")
    public void doBeforeAdvice(JoinPoint joinPoint){
            System.out.println("XXX");
    }
}
```

the error result:

[image: fail picture]

Is there a conflict between swagger and spring AOP?

Comment: I use spring AOP with Springfox. Never had any issue.

Comment: In the webUi,  I found that there is one proxy class in webUi. Its method is the same as that of the TestApi class. https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/2050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@egg

I setup the similar project and faced a same issue.

After setting the proxyTargetClass property to true in @EnableAspectJAutoProxy annotation as below, the issue got resolved.

`@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)`

This issue occurs only when we are using the interface for controller.

To quote the use of this property EnableAspectJAutoProxy from Java doc.

> Users can control the type of proxy that gets created for {@code FooService} using
>    the {@link #proxyTargetClass()} attribute. The following enables CGLIB-style 'subclass'
>    proxies as opposed to the default interface-based JDK proxy approach.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is for those who is still facing the issue
@Aspect is basically a filter. If you exclude the swagges resources it will start working.

you can use

```
  @Pointcut("within(com..*..*Controller)")
  @Pointcut("within(com..*..*Service)")
```

so it will scan only those pacakges which is starting from com...